# Swift: tableview cell change width and postion

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview

I create chatroom

I want user 1 chats position in right and user 2 chats position in left like below image

[image]

My code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyChatCell

        var frame = cell.frame
        let newWidth = frame.width * 0.50
        let space = (frame.width - newWidth) / 2
        frame.size.width = newWidth
        frame.origin.x += space

        cell.frame = frame

        return cell
}
```

But my code not work

Comment: @wings i cant. because my object is much. i want use codes for change this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consider using Anchor for your MyChatCellLeft and MyChatCellRight and anchor each example:

cell.messageLabel = "My Message"

cell.floatPosition = true // true left / false right

I must mention I haven't tested this. but you can try it and take it as a blueprint for what you are doing.. you also need to add some kind of logic of who is who... example user1 left user2 right. that depends on your logic...

```
class ChatBubbleCell: UITableViewCell{

var position: Bool = false

let messageLabel: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return label
}()

var floatPosition = Bool() {
    didSet {
        if(floatPosition == true){
            position = true
        } else {
            position = false
        }
    }
}

override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func setupViews(){
    addSubview(messageLabel)
    // lef position
    if position == true {
        let constrains = [messageLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 15),
                          messageLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -15),
                          messageLabel.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 20)
        ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constrains)
    } else {
        let constrains = [messageLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 15),
                          messageLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -15),
                          messageLabel.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: -30)
        ]
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(constrains)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: i get this error : init(coder:) has not been implemented

Comment: @TootiTooti are you using storyboard? if yes. please use storyboard cells. Im doing the example programatically. the easy way is to create 2 cells 1 positioning the cell on the right and the other on the left. and calling it on you UItableviewController depending on your logic. sounds clear to you? please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

- Consider the cell to be the whole row and use a subview to update frames.
- Update the frames on the method of *will display cell for row at index path*

Comment: i use this but not work : `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) { ... }`

Comment: but also.... Consider the cell to be the whole row and use a subview to update frames.